# ImageAdapter with custom pressed buttons

Tags: java, android, gridview, uibutton

I want my GridView with ImageAdapter to have custom pressed buttons. I already have custom buttons but onClick it creates an big orange onClick thing around the button. I just want onClick that it shows my custom pressed button. How should I make that easily?

ImageAdapter:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;
private final String[] buttonValues;

public ImageAdapter(Context context, String[] buttonValues) {
    this.context = context;
    this.buttonValues = buttonValues;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View gridView;

    if (convertView == null) {

        gridView = new View(context);

        // get layout from mobile.xml
        gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mobile, null);


        // set image based on selected text
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) gridView
                .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);

        String button = buttonValues[position];



        if (button.equals("homework")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.homework);
        } else if (button.equals("schedule")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_schedule);
        } else if (button.equals("planner")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.plannerbut);
        } else {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.settingsbut);
        }

    } else {
        gridView = (View) convertView;
    }

    return gridView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return buttonValues.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

}
```

And my Activity (GridView method):

```
private void setGridView() {
    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, MOBILE_OS));

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "homework", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 1:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "schedule", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case 2:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "planner",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case 3:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "settings",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }

        }
    });

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Wouter

Answer (score 1):

You can have your button use a custom drawable where you define the different states yourself.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/mybutton"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_button_selector" />
```

custom_button_selector.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/bg_pressed" /> 
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/bgalt" /> 
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_normal" /> 
</selector>
```

And then in bg_pressed/normal define the different buttons.

Have a look at http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imagebutton-selector-example/

Comment: At the moment i have it like this: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/homeworkpres" />
     <item android:state_focused="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/homeworkpres" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/homework" />
</selector>  but that doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding a ListSelector to my gridview and adding a selector in the ImageAdapter.